# Dynamic matrix initialization with scanf()

Tags: c, function, matrix, malloc

I need to make some functions for 2-dimensional arrays (a.k.a. matrixes) and the problem just starts with the first one.

I allocated the matrix in the heap memory using malloc() and then I tried to make a function that initializes the matrixes using a for loop of scanf()s, but after 3 times it takes the input, the program crashes.

Here is the code I made

```
void initMatrix(int **mat,int row,int col)
{
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0;j<col;i++){
            printf("Cell (%d,%d): ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r,c;
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    int **arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * c);

//    int count=0;
//    for (int i = 0; i <  r; i++)
//        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
//         arr[i][j] = ++count;

    for (int i = 0; i <  r; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }

    initMatrix(arr,r,c);
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
}
```

If I manually insert the content of the matrix, the program does work (without the initmatrix() function), I don't know why… I probably made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<col;i++)` --> `for(int j=0;j<col;j++)`

Comment: Searching for simplistic typos is something you are supposed to be able to do yourself.

Comment: Alright thanks, what an embarassing mistake. Since there is also a tag about functions, I was wondering how to make a function for multiplying two dynamic matrixes, I don't know if it's possible to ask another question but this one has got solved so fast.